# How make SQL JOIN and COUNT rows COUNT by groups in result?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

I have two tables country_champions and players. I need join it by fields contry/nationality and count players by nationality (first row in second table is bad and must be deleted).
How I can do that?
Result must be:

```
id   nationality   wins   players
---------------------------------
1    Brazil        5      1
2    Germany       4      1
3    Italy         4      2
4    Argentina     2      5
5    Uruguay       2      0
6    France        1      0
7    Spain         1      1
```

country_champions

```
id   country   wins
-------------------
1    Brazil    5
2    Germany   4
3    Italy     4
4    Argentina 2
5    Uruguay   2
6    France    1
7    Spain     1
```

players

```
id  name       club       nationality  wins
-------------------------------------------
1   id  name   club       nationality  wins
2   Bob Dylan  Villariba  Brazil       5
3   Chuck Nor  Barselona  USA          3
4   Ronaldo    Barselona  Germany      7
5   Brutallo   Real M     Italy        7
6   Max        Real N     taly         5
7   Mudila     Dynamo     Spain        3
8   Chuvila    Dynamo     Ukraine      3
9   Chuvila    Dynamo     Argentina    3
10  Player1    Dynamo     Argentina    4
11  Player2    Dynamo     Argentina    5
12  Player3    Dynamo     Argentina    8
13  Player4    Dynamo T   Argentina    8
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: There is plenty of examples on how to join, group and get counts on groups. Can you post the SQL you have tried so far? Which part you having issues with?

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh Expected result is the first data sample where it says `Result must be:`

Comment: @Fran, oops, now I see it. (Too little coffee is my only excuse.)

Comment: Guys, i'm movice in SQL and had a problem with count and group by syntax.

Comment: I know this might sound awful but it not intended to insult: @JackLoki novice or not, Stackoverflow is the last resort **after** you have tried everything yourself you can think of. Seeing you knew the terms `count`, `group by` etc.. there would have been plenty of examples out there using basic google searches to start from. After a little trial and error you could posted the SQL you had issues with and get help a lot faster too. If you are totally novice in something SO is not the place to learn on **in that context**, there is plenty of free and paid course to learn novice basics. IMHO

Comment: While humorous, this post is in my opinion pretty spot on explaining [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144) - Yes, it's satire but taken with a grain of salt there is some research effort expected, possibly to a slightly lesser extend than mentioned in that post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try left joining the players table and then doing a count():

```
Select c.id,
   c.country,
   c.wins,
   count(p.name) as players
from country_champions c
left outer join players p
   on c.country = p.nationality 
group by c.id,
   c.country,
   c.wins
```